# How is 14pt giving font size smaller than 12pt?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, document-classes, article

I am having problem with the statement:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

When I am giving 10 as the font size, it gets smaller than 12 as expected. Again, when I am giving 14pt as the font size it is again smaller than 12pt font size. Shouldn't it increase? Why is it decreasing?

Comment: How did you evaluate that `12pt` looks like `10pt`? Can you show how you did that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `article`, `report`, and `book` document classes recognize only three font size-related options: `10pt` (the default), `11pt`, and `12pt`.

Note that `14pt` is *not* a recognized option. If it's specified, it is not acted upon -- at least not at the document class level -- and the default of `10pt` is used. If you look in the log file, you'll find the following warning (not error) message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [14pt].
```

What to do? You need to switch to a different document class. Some possible candidates are `memoir`, the KOMA-Script classes (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook`), and the extsizes classes (`extarticle`, `extreport`, `extbook`). If you're otherwise happy with the `article` class, switching to `extarticle` may be best as doing so won't require learning anything new.